# How to delete mat-row from mat-table material design table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material's table component to display data, which is from an API. How do I delete a record of data from a table row?

HTML template:

```html
<div>
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userId}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> E-Mail </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.title}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.body}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="remove">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeAll()" matTooltip="Remove all">
          <mat-icon>clear_all</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user; let i = index;">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeAt(i)" matTooltip="Remove this score">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table> 
</div>
```

`user.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/from';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { SummaryService } from './summary.service';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.summaryService);
  displayedColumns = ['userId', 'id', 'title', 'body', 'remove'];
  usersList: Observable<User[]>;
  constructor(private summaryService: SummaryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private userService: SummaryService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.userService.getUsers();

  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

`summary.service.ts`:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable(
  //providedIn: 'root'
)
export class SummaryService {
  public baseurl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseurl);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the table is generated from the dataSource array, you can delete the and element of datasource on selected index using `splice` function. For example you can do something like below in the `removeAt` function according to your logic in user.component.ts file:

```
removeAt(i){    
    this.dataSource.splice(i,1);
    this.dataSource=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataSource));// this line is to refresh view and detect changes for updating table view

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but error occurred when compiling 
error TS2339: Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'UserDataSource' ?

Comment: This is because the `dataSource` object type does not have a splice method as you have provided no type with its declaration. Try setting its type to any i.e.   `dataSource:any = new UserDataSource(this.summaryService);`  in your user.component.ts file and see if it works.

Comment: dear Nabil, if you not busy, can u tell how to write delete function

Comment: now error in console " this.dataSource.splice is not a function"

Comment: The thing is, mat table is binded to dataSource, which means it is displaying dataSource in the table. If you change dataSource i.e. remove an element, the table will also change i.e. element will be removed. Which means delete element from dataSource to delete element of table. Splice is a function provided by javascript to remove array element. [Javascript Splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp). Can you log what is in the dataSource and show me the result when removeAt function is called?